# Connection of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}(a,b)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

In this question- [Connection of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on a toric manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807003/connection-of-mathcalon-on-a-toric-manifold), it is explained that the covariant derivative on $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is given by 
$$
\nabla=d+nA,
$$
where $A$ is the connection on a $U(1)$ bundle, $P$, such that the covariant derivative on $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is $\nabla=d+A$.

How does this generalize to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}(a,b)$, which is discussed here - [Proof of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}(a,b)$ is ample $\iff$ $a,b >0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234539/proof-of-mathcalo-mathbbp1-times-mathbbp1a-b-is-ample-iff?rq=1) ?

Would it be correct to say that the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}(a,b)$ is associated to a $U(1)\times U(1)$ bundle, whereby the covariant derivative is given by 
$$
\nabla=d+nA^{(1)}+mA^{(2)},
$$
where $A^{(1)}$ and $A^{(2)}$ are the components of the $U(1)\times U(1)$ connection, such that the covariant derivative on $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}(1,1)$ is $\nabla=d+A^{(1)}+A^{(2)}$?

References would be appreciated.